# How to make a map with the heatmap-look in QGIS based on values instead of the density of points?

Tags: categories, heatmap, qgis

I have measures from air pollution and I would like to show on a map where the pollution is biggest (the hotspots)

I would like to show my values from my attribut-tabel to show where I do have hotspots on my map (the bigger value, the bigger "circle" as in heatmap)

Is that possible?

I did try Interpolation, but i doesn't work - maybe I'm doing it wrong.

I did try to use the 'categories' in the label-changes, but I don't want the points in different colour like that. I would instead get the look like from the heatmap.

Answer (score 0):

In the toolbox (Ctrl+Alt+T in case you can't find it), you can experiment with "Multilevel b-spline interpolation" from SAGA geoalgorithms. It seems to be quite appropriate for your case.